# radion button list with textbox and hidden div inside (with sample image)

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, radio-button, listitem

im using asp controls.
i need that the RadioButton control will contain a textbox control.
i tried to do so - but thats not possible...

how can I get similar result to this image? 
the image shows example for radionbutton and textbox

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B7CLNmjk_GPpTkEtRUFBTzh5Rlk/edit?usp=sharing

click on the **+** will open a "add image" option...

so far this is the radiobutton list

```
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RBList" runat="server">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="4"></asp:ListItem>
                </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Comment: The radio button cannot "contain" a textbox, it is simple associated to the text box. Also, what is an "Add image" ?
Also, could you include the code that doesn't work ?
Also, what have you tried so far ?

Comment: there is no code... just a radio button list - i dont know how to make it look like in the example...

Comment: you have to add the elements one after the others. it isn't a special control, the example is just a succession of controls, just like any website ...

Comment: but it wont let me add elements between the listItem...

Comment: What list item ? please post your code, we cannot help you if we can't even see the problem.

Comment: code added. the radio button list

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use a repeater if you need dynamic binding on these controls:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" >
          <HeaderTemplate>
              <table>
              <tr>
                 <th>radiobuttons</th>
                 <th>textboxes</th>
              </tr>
          </HeaderTemplate>
          <ItemTemplate>
          <tr>
              <td>
                    <asp:RadioButton runat="server" />
              </td>
              <td>
                    <asp:Textbox runat="server" width="200px" />
              </td>
          </tr>
          </ItemTemplate>
          <FooterTemplate>
              </table>
          </FooterTemplate>
 </asp:Repeater>
```

Otherwise, if you need a defined number of elements, just use a static declaration (you can also use CSS instead of abusing of the table):

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>radiobuttons</th>
        <th>textboxes</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:RadioButton runat="server" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Textbox runat="server" width="200px" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:RadioButton runat="server" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Textbox runat="server" width="200px" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:RadioButton runat="server" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Textbox runat="server" width="200px" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```